# Is it possible to use Apache Helix with any other consensus service?

Tags: apache, hadoop, helix

I want to use Apache Helix with consensus service other than ZooKeeper. Is it possible to do so ? What api's need to be implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

Helix uses ZooKeeper to maintain the state of the cluster and to notify if there is any change in the cluster state. If you want to change to other consensus service, you're changing the Helix Architecture.

There are plenty of classes started with "ZK" or "Zk, for example, ZkListener, ZKHelixAdmin. You may need to implement another group of classes for other consensus service to provide the similar functionality.

Then for all the places where those Zookeeper related classes are used, you need to replace with new classes, which involves refactoring some other classes.